# Output only MAC address on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, networking

In Ubuntu, with command `ifconfig -a`, I obtain all the information about my ethernet/wifi interfaces.

But I need to obtain as output **only** the MAC address, like:

```
ab:cd:ef:12:34:56
57:89:12:34:ac:23
12:34:56:ab:cd:ef
```

How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `grep` with PCRE:

```
$ ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$'
74:d4:35:84:34:13
```

- `grep -P` will enable us to use `perl` compatible Regex
- `grep -o` will only take the matched portion of the line
- We have matched `HWaddr` before our desired match (MAC addresses) and then discard `HWaddr` by `\K` to print only the MAC addresses.

@Helio has mentioned an important point, this is highly dependent on your language i.e. `locale` settings. To overcome that you can use the `C` locale (uses ASCII character set) for this command only:

```
$ LANG=C ifconfig -a | grep -Po 'HWaddr \K.*$'
74:d4:35:84:34:13
```

Comment: You may use `LANG=C ifconfig -a` instead of `ifconfig -a` for non-english installations, can be problems with grep. (i.e. In my system, `HWaddr` is `direcciónHW`)

Comment: @Helio what if you type: `ifconfig -a | grep -i hw-*`?

Comment: @JoKeR just curious - is that `-*` supposed to mean something?

Comment: @muru not really I confused myself I thought he coudn't find `HW` but he stated on `HWaddr` and spanish as I guess/see `direcciónHW` so it's simply just `HW` can be ;)

Comment: Perl regex in `grep` "is highly experimental". If you want to use basic regex, the equivalent command is `ifconfig -a | grep -o 'HWaddr [[:xdigit:]:]*'` or, if you prefer, `ifconfig -a | grep -o 'HWaddr [a-f0-9:]*'`. I have omitted the trailing `$` because the output includes spaces after the MAC address, and probably you don't want those.

Comment: I have no HWaddr in my ifconfig output!

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04, I found that HWaddr was swapped out with "ether" So I had to do `ifconfig -a | grep -o 'ether [[:xdigit:]:]*'` instead.

Comment: That's a really good one since it doesn't need to install tools.

Answer (score 125):

You can access the `address` file for each device on the `/sys` virtual filesystem. The MAC address should be in `/sys/class/net/<device-name>/address`:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp1s0/address
34:17:eb:5d:88:7c
```

For all devices:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/*/address
34:17:eb:5d:88:7c
00:00:00:00:00:00
64:5a:04:69:50:45
```

Comment: +1 for not using a tool that's been deprecated for a decade :)

Comment: @hobbs Wait, which tool is that?

Comment: @detly ifconfig

Comment: @hobbs Woah. I was not aware of that. It does not print the deprecation warning on my machine.

Comment: @detly ifconfig's been deprecated for *years* now, and `ip` has also been around for years.

Comment: +1 for this since Ubuntu is removing ifconfig in 18.04 (if not prior releases).  I've written a one-liner based on this (previously using ifconfig and some awkward regex) to get the MAC address of the wifi card for a laptop. Adapt if you need it:
`cat /sys/class/net/$(iwconfig 2> /dev/null | grep '^w' | awk '{print $1}')/address`

Comment: In above 3 which one is the mac address

Answer (score 14):

Here are a few ways:

1. `grep`. There are various regular expressions that will pick these up. Here, I am looking for 5 repetitions of 2 letters or numbers followed by a colon, then any two characters. The `-i` makes the match case insensitive and the `-o` makes `grep` print only the matched portion. `-E` enables extended regular expressions. The same regex also works with PCREs (`-P`).

   ```
   ifconfig -a | grep -ioE '([a-z0-9]{2}:){5}..'
   ```
2. `sed`. The `-n` suppresses normal output and the `-r` enables extended regular expressions. Using the same regex as above, this script will attempt to replace everything on the line with the part of it that matches the regex. If the substitution was successful, the resulting line is printed (because of the `p` at the end of the substitution).

   ```
   ifconfig -a | sed -rn 's/.*(([a-z0-9]{2}:){5}..).*/\1/p'
   ```
3. `awk`. If the line starts with a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), and has 5 fields, print the last one.

   ```
   ifconfig -a | awk '/^\w/&&NF==5{print $NF}'
   ```
4. Perl, where, as usual, there are more than one ways to do it. This one is the same logic as the `awk` above. The `-a` tells perl to split each input line into the `@F` array.

   ```
   ifconfig -a | perl -lane 'if(/^\w/&&$#F==4){print $F[$#F]}'
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use the regex from the previous approaches:

   ```
   ifconfig -a | perl -lne '/(([a-z0-9]{2}:){5}..)/ && print $1'
   ```
5. Coreutils.

   ```
   LANG_ALL=C ifconfig -a | grep 'HWadd' | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f 5
   ```

Answer (score 9):

As some have commented, `ifconfig` is deprecated in favor of the `ip` command. So combining the various solutions and comments, I'd use:

```
$ LANG=C ip link show | awk '/link\/ether/ {print $2}'
FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
```

Answer (score 5):

`ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr | awk '{print $5}'`

If your system output is non-English in this command, then it makes sense to run it this way.

`LANG=C ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr | awk '{print $5}'`

This is applicable to all solutions.

Comment: Instead of using `grep` separately you could filter with `awk` directly like this:  `ifconfig -a | awk '/HWaddr/ { print $5 }'`

Comment: Yes, there are really lots of ways to get this done.

Comment: You may use `LANG=C ifconfig -a` instead of `ifconfig -a` for non-english installations, can be problems with grep. (i.e. In my system, `HWaddr` is `direcciónHW`)

Comment: Good notice. But in my Russian installation it is still HWaddr.

Comment: Your Russian installation may be, but my Spanish installation doesn't. **;-)** It can be a huge problem. Please, put `@Helio` at the begin of the comment. If not, I won't be notified.

Comment: `ip addr|grep ether|awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: `ip addr | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'`  ))))

Answer (score 1):

If you want a layer of abstraction away from the `/sys/class/net` interface you could use the `nmcli` command. For example, the `GENERAL` field of the `dev[ice]` object contains the interface type and hardware address (MAC):

```
$ nmcli -f GENERAL.DEVICE,GENERAL.TYPE,GENERAL.HWADDR dev show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:00:27:A7:C4:90

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s9
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         08:00:27:8E:46:AB

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
```

You can get the output in a more parsable form using the `-g | --get-values` option:

```
$ nmcli -g GENERAL.TYPE,GENERAL.HWADDR -e no dev show
ethernet
08:00:27:A7:C4:90

ethernet
08:00:27:8E:46:AB

loopback
00:00:00:00:00:00
```

So for example in a script you could do

```
$ nmcli -g GENERAL.TYPE,GENERAL.HWADDR -e no dev show | awk -v RS= '$1 ~ "ethernet" {print $2}'
08:00:27:A7:C4:90
08:00:27:8E:46:AB
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways for this :

**$ /sys/class/net//address**

this is the default location where u can find out the mac of any device.

**$ cat /sys/class/net/*/address**
is the easiest way to find out mac of hardware parts in ur ubuntu PC.

**$ ifconfig -a**
will also provide the same details with some extra data.
or you can use the grep to filter out the mac alone like :
**$ ifconfig -a | grep HWaddr | awk '{print $5}'**

other commands :

$ **ifconfig eth0**

$ **ip link show**

$ **ip -o link show eth0**

[Here](https://rulshi.blogspot.com/2022/08/terminal-command-to-get-mac-address.html) in this blog it is explaining the same and several other ways to get this.

Answer (score -1):

The below command is working for my ubuntu PC.

```
ifconfig | grep ether

ether c8:f7:50:fd:14:c8 txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Comment: This doesn't output "only" the Mac address, you need to use `awk` as well.