# Pull mac address via bash script

Tags: networking, command-line, ethernet, text-processing

A bit background.
Im creating a script that will run on USB stick with Ubuntu. It needs to pull various info from the current laptop its connected to and save it to a file.

Right now Im using "lshw -c network >> textfile.txt to pull network information.

But it gives me complete information for both wireless interface and ethernet interface while
I would only like to gather mac address (serial) under the ethernet interface.

is there any way I can do that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/628439/158442

Comment: @ArturMeinild with predictable network interface names, ethernet interfaces would all be `e<something or the other>`, so `/sys/class/net/e*/address`

Comment: Yeah ok, that could work too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output only MAC address on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628383/output-only-mac-address-on-ubuntu)

Comment: ... or perhaps `nmcli -g GENERAL.TYPE,GENERAL.HWADDR -e no dev show | awk -v RS= '$1 ~ "ethernet" {print $2}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isolating the output of `lshw` to Ethernet devices might work for you:

```
lshw -c network | grep -A 8 'Ethernet'
```

`-A 8` tells grep to include 8 lines after a match.

In addition, if you want to further reduce the output to only the lines with the MAC address (serial), you could grep again, like this:

```
lshw -c network | grep -A 8 'Ethernet' | grep 'serial'
```

... A more controlled way (not merely relying on plain text parsing) would be making use of `lshw`'s option `-json` to output in JSON structured data that can be processed much more reliably with tools like, for example, the `jq` tool likewise:

```
lshw -json -c network 2>/dev/null |
jq -r '.[] | select(."description" == "Ethernet interface") | .serial'
```

Comment: lshw -c network | grep -A 8 'Ethernet' | grep 'serial' works for me, what will the diffrence be with using "lshw -json -c network 2>/dev/null | jq -r '.[] | select(."description" == "Ethernet interface") | .serial'" ?

Comment: @pa-sc Explanation for that is added in the answer ... Please see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to return the MAC address of the Ethernet connection in a script.  The following line will actually produce the logical name of the Ethernet device and its MAC address.

```
sudo lshw -c network | awk '/logical name:/{ ETH=$3; next } /serial:/{ print ETH " " $2 }'
```

Depending on your script running on your USB the `sudo` may or may not be needed.

Here is an example of it running.

```
$ sudo lshw -c network | awk '/logical name:/{ ETH=$3; next } /serial:/{ print ETH " " $2 }'
eth0 94:de:80:c3:ba:dd
```

Or on a system with multiple NICs:

```
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo lshw -c network | awk '/logical name:/{ ETH=$3; next } /serial:/{ print ETH " " $2 }'
eth0 40:8d:5c:4f:11:fe      
eth1 de:9c:0b:f9:4d:ce
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have a reason to use `sed`:

`$ sudo lshw -c network | sed -nre 's/^ +serial: (.+)$/\1/p'`